# All my LibreOffice macros are gone. How to recover them?

Tags: libreoffice

I had about 10 saved macros. They appeared under LibreOffice Basic > My Macros > Standard > Module 1. Today, they're all gone. I don't have the slightest idea of how to go about trying to recover them. Any clues?

Comment: LO does this **way too often**.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can take a look in `~/.config/libreoffice`. If you recently upgraded LibreOffice to a new version, it's possible that your old settings weren't transferred. You should find your Basic macro's in `.xba` files in `~/.config/libreoffice/$VERSION/user/basic/Standard`, replacing `$VERSION` with one of the versions you have/had installed. For example, I apparently have two directories under `libreoffice/`, viz. `3/` and `4/`.

If this is the case, and you find your macro's under an older version, use the file manager to copy them to the macro directory of the most recent LibreOffice version. You should be able to see them again when next time you start the LibreOffice. I suggest that before you do this, you back up the original macro directory of the most recent version.

Comment: This happened to me. For some reason the module code (xba) was still in the location mentioned in the answer, but it was missing from the script.xlb file so wasn't being loaded. I simply added another line that begins <element> and set the name to the same as the filename of the xba file and then after restarting libreoffice, it worked. 
See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=78708